# Reference Another Sheet Using a Variable for the Sheet Name

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to reference each sheet in this formula by specifying the sheet name with the variable, "sheetname".  Does anyone know how to do this?

```
Sub PopulateRow()

Dim WS_Count As Integer
Dim I As Integer
Dim sheetname As String

WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

For I = 1 To WS_Count

    Worksheets(I).Activate
        sheetname = ActiveSheet.Name
    Worksheets(1).Cells(I, 1).Formula = "=sum('sheetname'!d:d)"

Next I

End Sub
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would pull the variable outside the quotes and concatenate with `&`.

```
Sub PopulateRow()

Dim WS_Count As Integer
Dim I As Integer


WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

For I = 1 To WS_Count

    Worksheets(1).Cells(I, 1).Formula = "=sum('" & Worksheets(I).Name & "'!d:d)"

Next I

End Sub
```

As a note I removed the sheet.Activate.  It will slow down the code and is not needed if done properly.

Comment: @Topher please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.  It is something only you can do.